# Preventing Windows 11 turning off sticky keys

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, sticky-keys

Like Windows 10, Windows 11 can activate sticky keys by pressing the shift key five times in a row.

Unlike Windows 10, Windows 11 quickly turns off sticky keys of its own accord; it seems to happen each time I use the control key with imperfect timing.

Is there a way to make Windows 11 not turn off sticky keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make Windows 11 not turn off sticky keys?

Yes. Windows 11. Turn Sticky Keys ON in Settings, Accessibility, Keyboard, Sticky Keys and sticky keys stay ON.

Works on my Windows 11 System.

Pressing a key x times is only a temporary method.